# How should I run code for 2 objects without warnings

Tags: java, templates, generics, types

I want to doStuff() for both objects, so I do this:

```
   for (XYChart.Series<String, Number> series : new XYChart.Series[]{firstSeries, secondSeries}) {
       series.doStuff();
   }
```

But that gives me a warning:

```
Unchecked assignment: 'javafx.scene.XYChart.Series' to 'javafx.scene.XYChart.Series'
```

How should I do actually do the for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays and generics don't work well together. your array does not have type params (and, really, can't have them), so the `<String, Number>` part? The compiler is trying to tell you: Well, uhh.... okay buddy. If you say so. I won't check this, and if you got this wrong, `ClassCastException` errors will occur in this code at weird places - places with no cast operations anywhere in sight.

The solution is not to mix arrays and generics. Given that generics are everywhere in java, that mostly means you shouldn't use arrays in java code (not lightly, anyway; they have their place, especially arrays or primitives). For example, this works fine:

```
XYChart.Series<String, Number> firstSeries = ..., secondSeries = ...;
for (XYChart.Series<String, Number> series : List.of(firstSeries, secondSeries)) {
   ...
}
```